# Bits of the primitive type in C

Tags: c, bit

Well, I'm starting my C studies and I was left with the following question, how are the bits of the primitive types filled in, for example, the int type, for example, has 4 bytes, that is 32 bits, which fits up to 4294967296. But if for example , I use a value that takes only 1 byte, how do the other bits stay?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {

        int x = 5; // 101 how the rest of the bits are filled
                   // which was not used?
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How would you pad an integer without changing its value? Think about it.

Comment: @FeiXiang In theory, signed integers in C can contain padding bits, in case of exotic number formats (1's compl, signed magnitude). But that scenario is not even worth pondering, since real world computers use 2's complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All leading bits will be set to `0`, otherwise the value wouldn't be `5`. A bit, in today computers, has only two states so if it's not `0` then it's `1` which would cause the value stored to be different. So assuming 32 bits you have that

```
5 == 0b00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
5 == 0x00000005
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be that way, but I was in doubt if the bits would be filled left or right. Another thing, coming out of the scope a bit, what would be the real use of bitwise?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your doubt about "filled left or right" depends on the endianness of the system. Bitwise operations can be used to set binary flags, at least that's how I see them being used.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun the bits are always filled to the most significant part. Just like in decimal we can write 0000123 for a 7-digit number. If we write zeros on the right then how can we differentiate between 123000 (which is 123) and 123000 (which is the real 123000)? In C we deal with **values**, not how the value is stored in memory which is what endianness about

Answer (score 0):

The remaining bits are stored with 0.

int a = 356;

Now let us convert it to binary.

```
 1     0    1     1     0   0   1   0   0
```

Now you get 9 bit number. Since int allocates 32 bits, fill the remaining 23 bits with 0.

So the value stored in memory is

```
         00000000 00000000 00000001 01100100
```

Comment: I ended up accepting the friend's response above, because he answered first, but thank you for your response too.

Answer (score 0):

The type you have picked determines how large the integer is, not the value you store inside the variable.

If we assume that `int` is 32 bits on your system, then the value `5` will be expressed as a 32 bit number. Which is `0000000000000000000000000101` binary or `0x00000005` hex. If the other bits had any other values, it would no longer be the number 5, 32 bits large.